# How to make a standard field for Redmine Required?

Tags: redmine

I'm using Redmine 2.4.0. I need to make a standard field (`Planned Start`) as required. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This functionality was added in v2.1.0 allowing configuration of required fields from a tab in the workflow settings.  Read more details on [Redmine Issue 703](http://www.redmine.org/issues/703)

[image]

Comment: Thanks .But I have already tried to do it and it is not reflecting.Is there any backend procedures that I need to do?

Comment: I agree that the above issue appears to add this functionality.  However, like @Van, I do not have a "Required" option in the dropdown for default fields.  For example - for the "Subject" field, I only have a "Read-only" option.  If I select that I then cannot create issues because "Subject field can't be blank."  Frustrating.

Comment: Im not sure.  Im not personally familiar with configuring Redmine, this is just what I was able to find on the subject.

Answer (score 0):

Field permissions are set up per "Role" and "Tracker". I set up field permissions all the time and I've never had any problems with them. Did you take care of these settings?